# replacing double click with long press / long tap event

Tags: meteor

I was trying to implement double click on mobile devices, but it seems like "dblclick" is broken.

```
'dblclick .myclass': function(){
      console.log("it works")

      };
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to implement a long press is to use the contextmenu event. Not only will this work for long press on mobile but it will fall back to a right click on a desktop.

```
Template.templateName.events({
    'contextmenu .myclass': function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        alert("it works");

    };
});
```

Comment: this didn't work for me - neither on mobile or desktop.